# HTML object element overlapping div's

Tags: c#, javascript, html, html-object

I am referencing a class in another project inside this div using the `<object>` element but the object dosen't seem to react to CSS and it overlaps outside of the div it's in when I scroll up and down, has anyone had this issue?

```
<asp:Panel ID="ObjectPanel" runat="server">
        <div id="ObjectContainer">
            <table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" width="100%" bgcolor="#ffffff" border="0"> 
                <tr>   
                    <td>    
                        <asp:Label ID="Label0" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>    
                    <td>    
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label></td> 
                </tr>
            </table>
                    <object id="ObjectId" classid="CLSID:50678BBE-06F5-4867-9D07-96DCEE2A0479" width="110" height="60">
                        <param name="BorderStyle" value="5"/>
                    </object>
        </div> 
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: It might be the order of your stylesheets if your not seeing the css being applied, i.e. you have stylesheet1 and stylesheet2, if there is css for an element/class/selector in each one whichever one is loaded last (the one on the bottom) is the one that will be applied. Also try margins for orverlapping issues

Comment: It's a user control acting as a drag and drop area